# Creating Fragments in Android?

Tags: android

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(tab.getPosition()==0)
        {
            FragmentA frag = new FragmentA();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);

        }
        else
        {
            FragmentB frag = new FragmentB();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
    }
```

The above code loads in fragments, the problem is it creates a new instance of each fragment, so going to and from tabs, the fragment reloads. What is the best way to make it so it does not create a new instance of each fragment eahc time and only uses the origial instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an attribute in your class

```
private frag = new Fragment();
...

    if(tab.getPosition()==0)
    {
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a method to push a fragement to the backstack or pop items off so we may reuse a fragment already in the back stack. The "name" param in the following function provides the best way to locate and pop back (if needed)

```
private void popToOrPushFragmentWithName(Fragment fragment, String name, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Scan the back stack for an entry with the given fragment name
    int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry entry = null;
    while (--count >= 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry check = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(count);

        if (check.getName() != null && check.getName().equals(name)) {
            entry = check;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (entry == null) {
        // There is no entry, so push the fragment
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(name);
        // might not need this next line (since you are using tabselected override)
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        // Pop back to the existing fragment (0 = not inclusive, so our fragment by index is on top)
        manager.popBackStackImmediate(entry.getId(), 0);
    }
}
```

Your onTabselected should look something like this :

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.getPosition()==0)
    {
        FragmentA frag = new FragmentA();
        popToOrPushFragmentWithName(frag, "FragmentA", ft);

    }
    else
    {
        FragmentB frag = new FragmentB();
        popToOrPushFragmentWithName(frag, "FragmentB", ft);
    }

}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: The line  FragmentA frag = new FragmentA(); creates a new fragment does it not, thus overwriting its previous state?

Comment: It will create a new fragment....but the popOrpush method will take the fragment and add to the screen if no fragment with that tag ("FragmentA" or "FragmentB") can can be found.

Comment: Isnt that a wasteful way of doing it, creating a new fragment everytime but never adding it to the screen?

Comment: Where can I find what the error was? i just get runtime exception

Comment: Look in the window pane called logcat in the debug perspective. Or Window > Show View > Logcat

Comment: There are no errors in logcat, the screen just says source not found.

Comment: Ok,  its compilation error.  Where is the error?  IS that method "popToOrPushFragmentWithName" added to your activity class where onTabSelected also is?